# Preact and FabricJS

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs, preact

I am starting to work on an application using preact, and I would like to know if it is possible to use FabricJS in preact. Can someone help me understand how I can do this?

Comment: So if preact is a version of react, then yes. Just do not try to bind fabricjs objects to react components, to me it does not makes sense

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Fabric.js with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565041/how-can-i-use-fabric-js-with-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Basic example

> To do that, place your Fabric instantiation into componentDidMount
>   
> [@RishatMuhametshin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39186522/6836839)

```
import { Component } from 'preact';
import { findDOMNode } from 'preact-compat';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const self = findDOMNode(this); // Or just the canvas ID
        const canvas = new fabric.Canvas();

        // fabric initialize...
        canvas.initialize(self, { /* Canvas options */ });
    }
    render() {
       return ( <canvas id="myCanvas" /> )
    }
}
```

### Global  example

```
//Somewhere else
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(); 

// MyComponent.js
class MyComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {

        //Initialize fabric js
        canvas.initialize("myCanvasId", { /* Canvas options */ });

        // fabric js stuff...
        const square = new canvas.Rect({
            fill: 'red',
            width: 50,
            height: 50
        });

        //Add object
        canvas.add(square);
    }
    render() {
       return ( 
           <div class={"myComponentClass"}>
               { /* your component content... */ }
               <canvas id="myCanvasId" />
           </div> 
       )
    }
}
```

You should check: [How can  I use fabric-js with react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565041/how-can-i-use-fabric-js-with-react)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this package for my own needs. You can try

https://github.com/indatawetrust/preact-fabric