# What react hook to use to trigger when an external object's property is changing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fabricjs

I am using Fabric js inside my react project ( I did that by following [this concept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70363968/13803179)). And I used `createContext` to fetch the canvas that is been created. There is a **Property window** component which is going to check what object is selected in the canvas. Initially, there is no canvas. It is created when the user imports an image. I was planning that there will be a `useState variable` , which will change whenever new object of canvas is selected. 
Objective is similar to [Fabricjs Kitchensink](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink)

```
import { fabric } from "fabric";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FabricContext } from "../../App";
export const PropertyWindow = () => {
   let canvas = useContext(FabricContext);
   // when the canvas will be created then canvas.current will point to `fabric.Canvas`
   let [selectedObject, setSelectedObject] = useState();
   return (
      <div>{/* Here I will add the styles of that selected object. */}</div>
   );
};
```

Here in this code I wanted to store the selected object inside `selectedObject` and also the value will change whenever a new object is created

Firstly I planned to create a function that will trigger whenever the canvas is created, for this
I used `useEffect` (like this: `useEffect(() => {},[canvas])` ) with `useState`, but it was not working (I was printing the canvas, and in the console it was showing `null` and that was when the page was loaded ). Later, my approach was to use `useEffect` in the parent component and send the canvas as a prop, here also it was showing the same thing.

Right now I am planning for classic javascript approach to solve this problem. I will be using `setInterval` like this

```
setInterval(()=>{
   if(canvas.current?.getSelectedObject() !== null){
      setSelectedObject(canvas.current.getSelectedObject()
   }
}, 300);
```

This will check inside the canvas if there is any object selected every *300ms* and if there is selected then it will change the `useState variable`. 
I have not used it yet, and I think there is a better way to fix this problem. I am not sure how to  even search for this problem over the internet since this is problem is too specific.

Comment: `useEffect` won't detect changes to ref, because changes to ref don't trigger a render. I don't understand why so you need state at all

Comment: @KonradLinkowski , Is there any hook for detecting the changes to ref. I consider using setInterval is not the correct approach for solving this problem. And also thanks, I atleast understood that this problem is actually related to detecting changes to ref.

Comment: I can make changes in `useCallback` where the canvas is created. But this will only help to trigger when the canvas is created. I want to create a function that needs to constantly check the value inside `canvas.current.getSelectedObject()`

Comment: But why do you need to do this?